# Using Ubuntu on Windows Phone 7

Tags: windows, phone, nokia

I was wondering if anyone has heard of or knows and plans for Ubuntu on Nokia Lumia 610. I am fed up with the current operating system on Nokia Lumia 610 and I want to replace it with Ubuntu, or if Ubuntu is not currently available I would like to replace it with any other operating system which is stable.

Thank you for taking your time to read my question.

M.Aslam